# iFrame and "max-height"

Tags: iframe, css

Any ideas for using `max-height` on a borderless/scrolless iFrame so if it ends up being too tall the browser doesn't render a giant black area to fill in the rest of the iFrame?

I've tried setting `height="100%"` and `max-height="xx"` but that doesn't seem to work.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your use of `height="100%"`, using the `=` operator, suggests you're trying to use in-line attributes. This *can* work, but usually works better with absolute measurements (so `700px` rather than a percentage). `max-height` isn't a valid attribute, so far as I'm aware, of any element ***except*** in stylesheets, so I'd suggest that you use CSS:

```
iframe {
    min-height: 200px; /* or whatever */
    max-height: 500px; /* or whatever */
}
```

You can, if you must, also use in-line styles, which would yield `<iframe src="..." style="min-height: 200px; max-height: 500px;">`

Also, while you *can* use percentages, to give `max-height: 80%`, this does seem to require that the parent element has a defined `height` of its own (I'm not sure if it's *all* browsers, or just one or two, but either way it seems a reasonable expectation in order that the browser can work out what 80% actually **is**).

Comment: css/inline seems to yield the same results, the content I'm iframing is a multi-page application.. the pages very from 400 px 900px.. if I set a min-height of the smallest page then the iFrame is too small... so what I need is height: 100% if it doesn't exceed 910px... sounds like it may have to be done with JavaScript...lol thanks however!

Answer (score 1):

A good JavaScript based answer seems to be the first solution from:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-adjust-the-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it/

Resizes the iframe to suit the content. I've found that you have to manually add a bit extra for height... go figure, but seems to work.

Here's the full mark-up and JS that works for me based on that solution:

```
    <iframe src="/app/index.html" style="width:100%;" frameborder="0" id="Iframe">
        Oops, your browser doesn't get Iframes. Click <a href="/app/index.html">Here</a> to proceed.
    </iframe>
    <script>
    //  Adjust the iframe height to exactly as much as required by the content
    var frame = document.getElementById("Iframe");
    frame.onload = function() {
      // add extra 50 pixels - in reality need just a bit more 
      frame.style.height = (50+frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight) + 'px';
      // not sure if this is really required. 
      // set the width of the iframe as the width of the iframe content
      frame.style.width = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth+'px';  
    }
    </script>
```